# Jersey can't find resources when deployed as JAR, but works in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jersey, grizzly

I'm embedding a Grizzly server within a java stand-alone app. I'm using Jersey to serve some resources using REST calls. While this works perfectly when I'm running/debugging in Eclipse, when trying to create a JAR using Export -> Runnable JAR, I get the following error all the time:

**SEVERE: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.**

Here is my class that starts the Grizzly Server:

```
/**
 * Constructor
 */
public RestServer(){
    //set up default initParams
    initParams.put( "com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages", packageName);
    initParams.put( "com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature", Boolean.toString(jsonParsing));
}

/**
 * Starts the Grizzly Server thread
 * @return  TRUE if start was correct
 */
public boolean startGrizzly(){
    if (grizzlyRunning){
        Logger.error(DEBUG_TAG, "Grizzly Server is already running");
        return false;
    }
    else{
        String hostString = host;
        String portString = Integer.toString(port);
        String server = "http://" + hostString + ":" + portString + "/";
        try {
            selector = GrizzlyWebContainerFactory.create( server, initParams );
            selector.setKeepAliveTimeoutInSeconds(-1);
            grizzlyRunning = true;
            return true;
        } 
        catch (IllegalArgumentException | IOException e) {
            Logger.error(DEBUG_TAG, "There was an error trying to start the Grizzly Server. Reason is " + e.getMessage());
            grizzlyRunning = false;
            return false;
        }
    }

}

/**
 * Stops the Grizzly Server thread
 * @return  TRUE if stop was correct
 */
public boolean stopGrizzly(){
    if (grizzlyRunning){
        selector.stopEndpoint();
        grizzlyRunning = false;
        return true;
    }
    else{
        Logger.error(DEBUG_TAG, "Grizzly is not running. Cannot stop it");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Package name contains the path to my other class that has the REST resources, in this case "com.mareculum.model". That said, this is the class that serves:

```
package com.mareculum.model;

@Path("/json")
public class RestResources {

    /**
     * Debugging tag
     */
    private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "RestResources";


    /**
     * Gets the JSON collection of data from itsaseusbuoys 
     * @return The JSON array containing the data from itsaseus buoys 
     */
    @GET
    @Path("/get/itsaseus_data_raw")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public ItsaseusDataEntity [] getItsaseusDataRaw() {
        Vector<ItsaseusDataEntity> ret = getItsaseusBuoysData();
        if (ret != null){
            return (ItsaseusDataEntity[]) ret.toArray();
        }
        else{
            return null;
        }
    }


    /**
     * Gets the JSON collection of data from itsaseusbuoys 
     * @return The JSON array containing the data from itsaseus buoys 
     */
    @GET
    @Path("/get/itsaseus_fusion_table")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public ItsaseusFusionTableRow [] getItsaseusDataEntity() {
        ArrayList<ItsaseusFusionTableRow> data = getDataFromItsaseusTable(); 
        ItsaseusFusionTableRow [] retArray = new ItsaseusFusionTableRow[]{};
        if (data != null){
            retArray = data.toArray(new ItsaseusFusionTableRow[data.size()]);
            return retArray;
        }
        else{
            return null;
        }
    }   

    /**
     * Gets the JSON data from NOAA 
     * @return The JSON object containing data from NOAA buoy 
     */
    @GET
    @Path("/get/noaa_fusion_table")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public BuoyRSSData [] getNoaaDataEntity() {
        ArrayList<BuoyRSSData> data = getDataFromNoaaTable(); 
        BuoyRSSData [] retArray = new BuoyRSSData[]{};
        if (data != null){
                retArray = data.toArray(new BuoyRSSData[data.size()]);
                return retArray;
        }
        else{
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, nothing really complex here. It looks to me something more related with how to pack the JAR file so Jersey knows where to look...I tried what was suggested here:
https://groups.google.com/d/msg/neo4j/0dNqGXvEbNg/xaNlRiU1cHMJ But it does not seem to work...

**UPDATE:** I managed to fix this by creating a hand made ANT file with the typical tasks: clean, build, jar, etc... I cannot really say what specific point of my ANT is fixing this issue...but it does. You can downloaded it [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16504598/build.xml) and reuse it if you happen to have the same problem, provided you change it accordingly to suit your project.

Answer (score 0):

hard to say without your web.xml, but check the following:

> Many reasons causing this “ResourceConfig” error message. Few
>   solutions that I know:
>
> ```
> com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages doesn’t exist in your web.xml.
> com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages included a resource that doesn’t include any jersey services.
> ```

Comment: Hi, I don't have a web.xml file, since I'm embedding grizzly, I don't need to. Actually, that is the idea of embedding the server in a Java stand-alone app, otherwise I'd use Tomcat or similar. Proposed solutions don't work, mostly because, it wouldn't work in Eclipse either if there where no package with resource at all...thx anyway

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you are going to do, but you may want to read this: http://www.vogella.com/articles/REST/article.html#restjersey before you proceed.

Comment: Hi, I already read that tutorial, which is great (as usual with Vogel), but I don't want having to use Tomcat, Glassfish, etc...specially since I'm only serving a couple of resources. Thus, I'm integrating a tiny REST server with Grizzly, altough Jetty can also be used for this. Nevermind, I managed to fix this with a hand made ANT file (see updated question) Thanks for the help anyway :)

Comment: I think you're right, it should be something with the resulting jar file, something is not getting included.